# USART communication, motors

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I have a problem with my Arduino code.
The code should behave like this: the first Arduino Uno receives data from the mobile app via Bluetooth. Then this data is sent to the other Arduino Uno which should control two DC motors (their direction and speed) using H-bridge.

Below is the code only for one motor.
Receiving Arduino receives data but the motors do not work, only the diode is on/off in appropriate moments. When I added the code for motors, everything works sending data works much slower.
Do you know what is wrong in the code, that it doesn't work properly?

Code for Arduino that sends data:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BT1(4,2); // RX, TX
SoftwareSerial port2(8,7); // RX, TX 
char data;
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   BT1.begin(9600);
   port2.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  BT1.listen();
  if (BT1.available() > 0){
    while (BT1.available() > 0) {
      data = BT1.read();
      port2.write(data);
    }
  }
}
```

Code for Arduino receiving data:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial port1(4,2);
char data = '0';

// Motor A
const int in1 = 10;
const int in2 = 9;
const int en1 = 11;

// Motor B
const int in3 = 6;
const int in4 = 5;
const int en2 = 3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  port1.begin(9600);


  //Enabling pins responsible for motor B and and setting them as output
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(en2, OUTPUT);
}

void demo1() {
  /************** For motor B ****************/
  //Set direction
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);

  //Set speed from 0 to 255
  analogWrite(en2, 250);


  delay(5000);

  /************** For motor B ****************/
  //Change direction
  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);


  delay(5000);
}

void stopMotor() {
  //Stopping the motor B
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (port1.available() > 0){
    Serial.println("Data from other Arduino:");
    data = port1.read();
    Serial.println(data);
    if (data == '1') {
      demo1();
    } else {
      stopMotor();
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: when you mention the LED do you mean the one on the H-bridge?

Comment: You say "_when I added the code for motors, everything works [but] sending data works much slower_". Could that be because the receiving Arduino is first processing the command, including two delays of 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes, I meant diode on H-bridge

Comment: That's true but can I make it the other way, that these two delays won't make the communication slower?